# Dynamic Workbook and Worksheet name in Macro or VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that works: (am currently using Excel 2003)

```
Sub test_copy1()    

Dim wb1 As Workbook     
Dim wb2 As Workbook     
Dim ws1 As Worksheet     
Dim ws2 As Worksheet      

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Workbook2.xls")     
Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook     
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Run 1")     
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet3") 

ws2.Range("A1:h30") = ws1.Range("A177:H206").Value  

End Sub
```

In the current Workbook "Sheet 3"
Cell J1 = Workbook2.xls
Cell J2 = Run 1

How can I feed the information from the current Workbook "Sheet 3" into the macro from the cells so that it may be changed as needed and still work?

What I mean is to have 2 cells that can change in a sheet, either by drop down or manually filled in on the current workbook sheet "sheet 3".
Cell: J1 would equal a file name (Workbook2.xls) and J2 would equal a sheet name (Run 1).

The user would be able to change the file name and sheet name when they needed and then hit a button to process the copy and paste.

I would like the code to take the information from the cells and put them into the code instead of "hard" coding the file name of the workbook and sheet.

I hope that makes more sense

Thank you for any help.

~DA

-----UPDATE----

I have tried this code but it keeps crashing on the first Set Wb1=

```
    Sub test_copy1()

        Dim wb1 As Workbook
        Dim wb2 As Workbook
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet

        Set wb1 = Workbooks(ws2.Range("J1"))
        Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(ws2.Range("J2"))
        Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet3")

        ws2.Range("A1:h30") = ws1.Range("A177:H206").Value

    End Sub
```

------Update -------

I got it to work using you all examples and adding .Value after the range :)

```
Sub test_copy1()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet3")

    Set wb1 = Workbooks(ws2.Range("J1").Value)
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(ws2.Range("J2").Value)

    ws2.Range("A1:h30") = ws1.Range("A177:H206").Value

End Sub
```

Thank you, thank you for all your help!!

Comment: `Set wb1 = Workbooks(ws2.Range("J1"))` and `Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(ws2.Range("J2"))`?

Comment: byw, does your workbook with name from `J1` is always opened? If not does `J1` contains only wb name or full path?

Comment: Yes both workbooks are always open. I will try your suguestions now.

Comment: J1 just has the file name. Does it need the full path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub test_copy1()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet3")

    Set wb1 = Workbooks(ws2.Range("J1").Value)
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(ws2.Range("J2").Value)

    ws2.Range("A1:H30").Value = ws1.Range("A177:H206").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: It errors here "Set wb1 = Workbooks(ws2.Range("J1"))". I have checked the file name that is in J1 and it is correct to the second file that is open.

Comment: try to add `MsgBox ws2.Range("J1")` just before `Set wb1 = Workbooks(ws2.Range("J1"))`. Does it give you correct workbook name? Also try `Set wb1 = GetObject(ws2.Range("J1"))`

Comment: I used your code, and added .Value after the Cell name and it worked :). I just need to test it on the older version of Excel, but so far so very good. thank you

Comment: one more thing: you should use `ws2.Range("A1:H30").Value = ws1.Range("A177:H206").Value` instead `ws2.Range("A1:H30") = ws1.Range("A177:H206").Value` (otherwise it copies nothing) - I've already updated my answer

Comment: Thank you again! I have been fighting with this for days now :)