# Modify an existing data entry excel spreadsheet to save data to another xls

Tags: vba, excel

I'm after just the most simple of excel data entry forms.  I've made a slightly modified version of a very available free xls form data entry sheet, and I'd like to modify it so it exports the data entered by the user to another spreadsheet (currently it exports to another worksheet).

Here's the code I have so far.

```
Option Explicit
Sub UpdateLogWorksheet()
Dim historyWks As Worksheet
Dim inputWks As Worksheet

Dim nextRow As Long
Dim oCol As Long

Dim myRng As Range
Dim myCopy As String
Dim myCell As Range

'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
myCopy = "D5,D7,D9"

Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
Set historyWks = Worksheets("PartsData")

With historyWks
    nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End With

With inputWks
    Set myRng = .Range(myCopy)

    If Application.CountA(myRng) <> myRng.Cells.Count Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

With historyWks
    With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    End With
    .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
    oCol = 3
    For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
        historyWks.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
        oCol = oCol + 1
    Next myCell
End With

'clear input cells that contain constants
With inputWks
  On Error Resume Next
     With .Range(myCopy).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
          .ClearContents
          Application.GoTo .Cells(1) ', Scroll:=True
     End With
  On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

It takes 3 fields entered by the user, and also takes the `authorid` and date/time and places it into a worksheet in the xls document.  I'm looking to send this data to another specified spreadsheet/xls instead.

Assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.  Sorry, coding really isn't my thing.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you just need to set the names of the two workbooks, in a similar way to how you have the worksheets. Then when you reference the worksheets in the code, preceed it with the variable you have given the workbooks (assuming the other workbook has the same sheet name and structure as the existing one).

This previous question explains how to reference the workbooks:
[Dynamic Workbook and Worksheet name in Macro or VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502808/dynamic-workbook-and-worksheet-name-in-macro-or-vba)